# CSV Output with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

Currently a PowerShell script is outputting individual reports for my work. The contents of the report contain a path, a filename and date/time info in the following format:

```
    Directory: E:\A7\Capture One Session\Output\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
-a----        8/15/2017   4:06 PM        4379427 B0725Y6ZNM.PT04.PC_410.jpg
```

I am now looking for a PowerShell script that would concatenate these individual .txt reports into a single running .csv document. Currently the .txt outputs all live in the below location, they are the only .txt files in the location:

```
\\Serverpath\reports\
```

Considering the above .txt output example, I would like the .csv output to spread the following data across four columns as such:

```
| 8/15/2017 | A7 | B0725Y6ZNM | PT04 |
```

The Date, the first folder in the directory path (A7) and the first two portions of the file name (B0725Y6ZNM & PT04).

This type of output is beyond my current ability and I am having trouble creating a rough draft of the code. I will update what I have when I get a functioning script. Any help getting started would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is giving me the data inside the .txt files, but it is not split into the columns like I want:


`$filepath = '\\Serverpath\reports\*.txt'
$reportData = Get-Content $filepath
$reportData | Out-File '\\Serverpath\reports\report.csv'`

Comment: I would be much easier to update the script that is generating these text files that it will be to parse the text output. The `.txt` files appear to be the formatted output of `Get-ChildItem`. Getting the information from a object that is the output `Get-ChildItem` would be easy, after sending that formatted to a text would be hard.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice @BenH. I was thinking the same thing but wanted to avoid altering existing scripts. I appreciate it!